# SSRS 2008 Access from Desktop PC

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 and SSRS 2008 running on a desktop PC for to be used for development. This PC is registered under my user id and I can remote desktop into it and connect to SSRS just fine from my laptop (also registered under my user id). Also, I can access the website from my laptop when I am NOT logged into the PC (i.e. after a reboot and before logging in).

When another team member tries to connect to SSRS via the web (SSRS is running on port 8080) he cannot connect. I have tried different options like adding his as a user on the PC and granting permissions for him on the Home folder in Report Manager. Nothing seems to work. He CAN connect to the PC over remote desktop so I know that the connectivity is there and since I can access port 8080 from my laptop he should be able to access port 8080 as well.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to grant access to this team member? I am open to all ideas that do not involve writing custom code (which i really should not have to do to fix this issue). This used to work with SSRS 2005 but I know that it used IIS then and now it uses http.sys directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleague needs permissions at the file system level to the SSRS folders:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager

and

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer

in addition to access granted to the website in IIS.
Are these computers in a domain? 
What operating system?

Comment: I will try the permissions in the morning. I don't understand how IIS is involved...it is not even installed on the computer. They are in a domain yes and both running Windows XP.

Comment: I added the user to the Administrators group on the server (desktop PC) and he was able to access the website. This works for my specific purpose (he can also be a backup admin in case someone else needs to log into the system) but not a good solution for people outside my team.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your network it seems difficult to diagnose this issue. He cannot connect to port 8080 at all, as though the port was blocked? Or is SSRS replying with an error page?

If he can't connect to port 8080 at all it is almost certainly a packet filtering or firewall issue. What happens if you use a telnet application to send an HTTP GET request from his computer to the server on port 8080?

If there are error messages describing them would be quite helpful in finding a resolution.

Comment: It seems he can connect and SSRS tries to do something but fails. The connectivity between computers/ports seems to be working fine...I believe it is some permission issue in SSRS somewhere (or possibly on the PC that hosts SSRS). I will try to get some error messages in the morning but from what I remember, nothing stood out.